# Using multiple languages in one project

Tags: programming-languages, language-design, complexity-theory

From discussions I've had about language design, it seems like a lot of people make the argument that there is not and will never be "one true language".  The alternative, according to these people, is to be familiar with several languages and to pick the right tool for the job.  *This makes perfect sense at the level of a whole project or a large subproject that only has to interact with the rest of the project through a very narrow, well-defined interface.*

On the other hand, using lots of different languages seems like a very awkward thing to do when trying to solve lots of small subproblems elegantly.  In other words, IMHO, general purpose languages that are decent at everything still matter.  As a trivial example, let's say you need to do the following:

1. Read a bunch of data in some arbitrary format from a file.  Check it for errors, etc.  (Best done in something like Perl).
2. Load this data into matrices, do a bunch of hardcore matrix ops on it (Best done in something like Matlab).
3. Run a custom, computationally intensive routine on it that must be fast and space-efficient (Best done in C or C++).

This is a fairly simple project, other than writing the computationally intensive custom matrix processing routine, yet the only good answer about what language to use seems to be a general-purpose one that's decent at everything.

What am I missing here?  How does one use multiple languages effectively to take advantage of each of their strengths?

Comment: The key is to select one common "glue" language that can move parameters and return values around between each specialized sub-step written in other languages, and will act as the 'main program' in some fashion. That is *still* best done in Perl, which I find rather annoying!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have worked on many projects that contain a fairly diverse mix of languages. Unless it's a .NET project, you usually use these different languages at different tiers or in different processes. Maybe your webapp is in PHP and your application server in java. So you do not really "mix and match" at method level.

In .NET and for some of the java vm languages the rules change a bit, since you can mix much more freely. But the features of these languages are mostly defined by the class libraries - which are common. So the motivation for switching languages in .net is usually driven by other factors, such as which language the developers know. F# actually provides quite a few language features that are specific for that language, so it seems to be a little bit of an exception within .NET. Some of the java VM languages also add methods to the standard java libraries, adding features not available in java.

You do actually get quite used to working with multiple languages as long as all of them have good IDE support. Without that I really think I would be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Embedded languages like Lua make this pretty easy. Lua is a great dynamic language along the lines of Ruby or Python and allows you to quickly develop high quality code. It also has tight integration with C, which means you can take advantage of C/C++ libraries and optimize performance critical sections by writing them in C or C++.

In scientific computing it's also not uncommon to have a script that for example will do some data processing in Matlab, use Perl to reformat the output and then pass that into another app written in Matlab, C or whatever. This tends to be more common when integrating apps that have been written by different people than when developing something from scratch, though.

Answer (score 1):

You're saying that the choices are either a) write everything in one language and lose efficiency, or b) cobble together a bunch of different executables in order to use the best language for each section of the job.

Most working programmers pick option c: do the best they can with the languages their IT departments support in production. Generally programmers have some limited language choice within a particular framework such as the JVM or CLR - so it's neither the toolbox utopia nor the monolanguage ghetto.

Even LAMP and Rails support (demand, really) different languages at different levels - HTML, Javascript, Ruby, C in the case of Rails. If you're writing software services (which is where most of the interesting work is happening these days) then you're hardly ever writing in just one language. But your choices aren't infinite, either.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the most difficult part of your task.  Is parsing the file the most complex part?  A good language for reading files, and then manipulating them might be the most pertinent choice.

Are the math transformations the most difficult part?  You might want to suck it up and use matlab, feeding it in with scripts or other home grown tools.

Is performance the most important part?  How much calculation will be done versus the transformations and parsing?  If 90% of the work done will be on calculation, and the other parts are only transitory, then consider a C/C++ solution.

There's nothing inherently wrong with playing to multiple language strengths in a simple solution, especially if you don't mind gluing it together with scripts.  However, the more languages and modules that you integrate increase your dependencies, and the more dependencies you have, the more and more difficult it becomes to distribute and maintain your app.  That's where the real trade-off lies: the fewer technologies, libraries, and bits of software you need to run the app, the simpler it becomes.  The simpler the app, the more maintainable, distributable, debuggable, and usable it becomes.

If you don't mind the extra overhead of integrating the multiple pieces of technology, or that overhead will save you an equal or greater amount of development time, go right ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fine.  If you set it up as an n-tier setup where each layer accesses what is below it the same way (SOAP/XML/COM, etc), I have found it to be invisible in the end.

For your example, I would choose one language for the front end that is easy, quick, flexible, and can make many, many, many, many, many types of calls to different interfaces such as com, corba, xml, .net, custom dll libraries, ftp, and custom event gateways.  This ensures that you can call, or interface with any other lanugage easily.

My tool of choice for this is Coldfusion from working with ASP/PHP/Java and a bit of Ruby. It seems to have it all in one place and is very simple.  For your specific case, COldfusion will allow you to compile your own library tag that you can call in your web code.  Inside the tag you can put all the c code you like and make it do whatever you want.

There are free and open source versions of Coldfusion available and it is fantastic for making Java and .NET calls naively from one code base.  Check it out, I really feel it might be the best fit as it's made for these kinds of corporate solutions.

I know PHP can be pretty good for this too depending on your situation, and I'm sure Asp.net isn't too far behind.

Answer (score 0):

My work in multiple languages has involved just a simple mix of C# and C++/CLI (that's like C++ with .NET if you haven't heard of it). I do think that it's worth saying that the way .NET and Visual Studio allow you to combine many different languages together means that you won't have as high of an overhead as you would normally expect when combining two languages - Visual Studio keeps it all together. Given that there are many .NET clones of various languages - F#, IronPython, IronRuby, JScript.NET for example - Visual Studio is quite a good way in which you can combine various languages.

Down to the technical level which sounds like what you're interested in, the way it's done in Visual Studio is you must have one project for each separate language, and each project gets compiled into an assembly - basically meaning it becomes a library for the other projects to use. You'll have one main project which drives everything and calls the other libraries. The requirement of each different language having to be a different project means you wouldn't change languages at the method level, but if you are doing a large enough application that you can logically separate it into multiple projects, it can actually be quite useful. In particular, the separation and abstraction can make things easier overall.